# The button is supposed to bring a new random quote every time it’s clicked but nothing happens when I click it

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to include a button element in my react component that brings a new random quote every time it’s clicked but I am stuck because the button doesn’t do anything when I’m click. This is for the free code camp random quote generator challenge. I want to make the sure the button works before I do any styling and anything else. I am new to react and this is my first challenge

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { qoute: "", randomQoute: "" };
    this.newQoute = this.newQoute.bind(this);
  }
  async componentDidMount() {
    let response = await fetch("https://type.fit/api/quotes");
    let data = await response.json();
    this.setState({ qoute: data });
    let randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * data.length);
    this.setState({ randomQoute: data[randomIndex] });
  }
//this is the function that is called every time the button is clicked  
 newQoute() {
    let randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * qoute.length);
    this.setState((state) => ({ randomQoute: state.qoute[randomIndex] }));
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Quotes</h1>
        <h2>{this.state.randomQoute.text}</h2>
        //this is the button element 
    <button onClick={this.newQoute}>New Qoute</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not accessing the qoute variable correctly, in the following function:

```js
newQoute() {
    let randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * qoute.length);
    this.setState((state) => ({ randomQoute: state.qoute[randomIndex] }));
}
```

when calculating the randomIndex, you need to access the qoute variable from the state like so: `this.state.quote`

Make sure to access `state` variables using `this.state.[variableName]`

So your function will become:

```js
newQoute() {
    let randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.state.qoute.length);
    this.setState((state) => ({ randomQoute: state.qoute[randomIndex] }));
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This has worked. The button is working now

Answer (score 0):

Edit: randomQuote is an empty string. When you are setting the state of `randomQuote` to `state.quote[randomIndex]` it should just be an entire string correct? I don't know how the api is setup. But if its an array index it shouldn't have a `key` of `text` it should just be a string value. so try

```
render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Quotes</h1>
        <h2>{this.state.randomQoute}</h2>
        //this is the button element 
    <button onClick={this.newQoute}>New Qoute</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I copied and pasted the code I didn’t realize the first part got cut out but I have edited it accordingly and that is the full JavaScript file I have currently. Please advise me on the errors you have seen

Comment: I’ll take a look again. Do you get any browsers errors in the console?

Comment: I ran for qoute and randomQoute defined in the state and they both returned correct results. No errors

Comment: @musinga check again for updated answer. If that doesn't answer it, could you provide what your quote object looks like?

Comment: The api is an array of objects which all have text and author keys so this wouldn’t help. But I have found a helpful answer. 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/73084620/19399519 This is what I was doing wrong